# How to update excel data into existing XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, excel

I want to add excel file data into an existing XML file and a particular tag.

I want to add excel data of upc code into the upc tag of the XML file using PHP.

My excel file format is:

[image]

I want the following XML format data.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, researched ? We can help you on a precise point, but you need to show some effort trying to solve this problem by yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("yourxmlfilename.xml");
 $prod = $xml->Products;
 print_r($prod->Product->count());
 for($i=1; $i<=$prod->Product->count();$i++){
   $str = (string) $prod->Product[$i]->ExternalId;
if($str == 'mobilesn1'){
    $c = $prod->Product[$i]->UPCs;
    print_r($prod->Product[$i]->UPCs->UPC);
    if((string)$prod->Product[$i]->UPCs->UPC !="895623" ){
    //unset($prod->Product[$i]->UPCs->UPC);
    $c->addChild('UPC', '895623');
    $xml->asXML("yourxmlfilename.xml");
    }
  }
}
```